# Visual Studio 2019 no designer support on Windows Forms on .Net 5.0

Tags: windows-forms-designer, .net-5

It seems like I've lost designer support for Windows Forms on .NET 5.0. Everything was working ok last week, but now, as you can see, there's no designer support:

[image: No designer support for Windows Forms]

This is not a new .NET 5.0 Windows Forms projet, it's been migrated from .NET 4.8. I'm using Visual Studio 19 16.8.4.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: have you check the csproj if [UseWindowsForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-5.0#project-file) is still included?

Comment: I've followed those instructions during migration and everything was working fine. I've managed to recover the designer, but I'm not sure on how I did it. I've edited the csproj manually and reverted the changed (git) and everything started working again...I really don't know why though...

Comment: which changes have you reverted?

Comment: That's the thing: I've opened it on xml editor, removed the clickonce section, saved it and reload it. The designer was back. I've reverted the changes (discarded all local git changes) and recovered the clickonce section. and the designer was still visible...in the end of the day, I didn't change anything. Now, since I'm constantly changing branches (we're not publishing the net 5.0 version yet because there are several open issues), there might be some sort of issues with the constant changes from .NET 4.8 to .NET 5.0...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

[How to migrate a Windows Forms desktop app to .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Preview WinForms designer in Visual Studio.

To enable the designer, go to Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features and select the Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps option.